# some commands display command not found in ubuntu mosquitto broker

Tags: mosquitto

I have installed `mosquitto` broker on `ubuntu`. I used `apt-get update`, `apt-get upgrade` followed by installation of `mosquitto` and `mosquitto-clients`. I had installed it once and since some commands werent working i removed then using `sudo apt-get purge --remove mosquitto` and `sudo apt-add-repository --remove ppa:mosquitto-dev/mosquitto-ppa`and installed again.I am able to publish subscribe to topics but `systemctl`,`mosquitto_passwd` and `mosquitto -v` commands dont seem to work.I get

> command not found

.Have i done anything wrong during installation? Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you removed them then why do you expect to still be able to run them?

Comment: i have installed it again..